# Debugging in the past and now

Tags: debugging, testing, software-design

I'm enrolled now in this course on Udacity [Software Development Process](https://eg.udacity.com/course/software-development-process--ud805) and the instructor said that one of the methods used to fill the gap between the software complexity and developers productivity debugging moved from printing lines to symbolic debugging.
Anyone can illustrates what that actually means?

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Like instead of printing intermediate stuff in the program itself, now we can use the debuggers utilizing the symbolic debug information compiled into the executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formerly:

```
print("Before doing this ...");
int x = dothis();
printf("Before doing that ...; x=%d", x); 
int y = dothat(x);
```

Today:

[image: Debugging in Visual Studio]

All local variables can be seen in the debugger and can be modified there. The call stack can be seen in the debugger. You can stop at any line of code and even move the instruction pointer back to a previous line.

All print statements are unnecessary. There's no risk of forgetting them in the source code, making is slower and dangerous (remember Apple's print password bug).

To achieve that, the debugger uses symbols, stored by the compiler in addition to the EXE file. On Windows, they are stored in a PDB file (program database), thus giving a small exe for the customer and additional data for the developer.

Comment: If this answer is sufficient for you, you can mark it with the checkmark so that others see that the question is answered.